# How to change default automount USB path to /mnt/sdXX?

Tags: udev, usb-drive, automounting, autofs, udisks

Default mount path with udisks2, udiskie is /media/XXXXX
On some distributions /media/user/XXXXXX

How to change automount path for USB drives to a shorter /mnt/sdb1 /mnt/sdc2 etc.

With udisks2, udiskie, or any other program?
autofs, usbmount, tinymount, uam

Comment: You could achieve this by modifying /etc/fstab. Does it absolutely need to be done via a program? I could show you a modified config to get you started. You'll benefit in the long run if you learn fstab.

Comment: @zedheadted withou additional program it is even better. I'm using Devuan with runit, does fstab automounting requires systemd? In any case it would be benefitial to see the config.

Comment: No, not to my knowledge. I'm running MX Linux with sysvinit and it can read my fstab config just fine. I'll put together a pretty close config for yours with explanation shortly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to automount this drive by adding it to your `/etc/fstab` via something relatively permanent like its `UUID`. To get its `UUID`, run `blkid` in the terminal. The output should look like this:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="87ac54cc-420a-4e1b-8c59-075b4b8fe071" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="EXTRASPACE" PARTUUID="6b1ec542-12e7-4445-bce0-42e37ca569da"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="rootMX21" UUID="eeab14e6-7285-4a07-bf12-1e019c44ef6d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="07431b3f-2d82-4c7e-acbc-b6ad9656bc3d"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="a0c26590-8688-4346-9265-4f340fba5897" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8dba9f94-bf57-c848-8f3c-52e75715163c"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="eb571bca-e4ca-467a-9cc3-7c71f685e5d2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8b352f72-ff6e-3746-a088-d157ce83a53c"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="d825bffd-5e65-4d82-bbe0-9162928b6dab" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="740b39fc-93b6-426b-b153-9624a5dc7bdd"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI System" LABEL="EFI System" UUID="B196-A0D5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="90d290dc-9561-48ed-b57c-a31a7cceb243"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Extreme SSD" UUID="5EDA-9FC9" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="exfat" PARTUUID="02d1225f-01"
```

If you haven't already, make the directory under `/mnt`. Then find the `UUID` that matches the `/dev` of your USB device. Copy it, and open `/etc/fstab`. Here, you make a new line for the USB device, replacing `$usbDeviceUUID` with the `UUID`, `$mountpoint` with the directory you made under `/mnt`, and `$fs` with the filesystem it uses. It should look close to the 3rd line in the below config when you're done. Don't modify your `/` and `/home` lines, as those were likely generated at install.

```
UUID=eeab14e6-7285-4a07-bf12-1e019c44ef6d / ext4 discard,noatime 1 1
UUID=a0c26590-8688-4346-9265-4f340fba5897 /home ext4 noatime 1 2
UUID=$usbDeviceUUID $mountpoint $fs defaults,noatime 1 3
UUID=d825bffd-5e65-4d82-bbe0-9162928b6dab swap swap defaults 0 0
```

There are probably other "permanent" identifiers you can use, but the UUID is easy to get and won't change unless/until you clone another drive onto your USB drive.

Comment: System adds devices from /etc/fstab during boot, if drive is not there system complains. For removable USB devices something must discover them and run mount scenario. In my case udiskie can discover and mount drive according to /etc/fstab as from your config. But this is probably partial solution because I don't know how properly configure udiskie.